# Laravel 5.2 Incluir Campo para Autenticação

Tags: laravel-5

Boa tarde,
Gostaria de uma luz para alterar a forma que o Laravel realiza a autenticação, adicionei uma coluna (***login***) na tabela users
Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para ao invés de autenticar com as colunas email e password eu utilize as colunas login e password.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: dá uma olhada: nesse exemplo:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148446/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-costumizada-com-cpf-e-email/151477#151477

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No model `User.php`, altere a linha abaixo com as colunas que deseja:

`protected $fillable = ['nome', 'email', 'password'];`

Sendo `email` e `password` responsáveis pelo login no sistema.

Comment: então, o que eu quero é justamente que os campos responsáveis pelo login sejam outros, no meu caso trocaria o campo _email_ por _loginUsuario_ por exemplo

Comment: Beleza, seguiu as instruções ?

Comment: sim.. 
alterei também o meu login.blade.php com, onde era _email_ coloquei _login_ mas na hora de logar ele não faz nada, volta para mesma tela de login