# Autenticação customizada com CPF e E-MAIL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou pensando em uma forma de autenticar usuários usando o e-mail e o CPF do mesmo, até agora não achei uma forma de fazer, alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
public function auth(Request $request) {
    $credenciais = $request->only('cli_email', 'cli_cpf');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Framework Laravel, possui uma forma de autenticação com a instância da *classe* `User`, sendo então possível conferir outros dados relevantes a seu proposito para ter acesso ao sistema, seguindo exemplo:

```
$user = User::where('cpf', $cpf)->where('email', $email)->first();
if ($user) // se verdade existe um usuário com essas informações
{
    Auth::login($user); //efetuando a operação de autenticação
}
```

mas, ***não seria uma falha de segurança***?, porque, é fácil descobrir o CPF e o E-mail de algum usuário, a senha deveria também ser informada por ser um dado de cada usuário.

Comment: Concordo com você quando diz que é uma falha de segurança, mas infelizmente o cliente precisa desse tipo de login, deixei o mesmo bem informado sobre a situação, muito obrigado pela resposta, já havia finalizado o job, mas mesmo assim ainda considero como resposta.

Comment: Sem problemas @geekcom, foi um alerta, e cliente é cliente nem sempre entende o nosso trabalho ... !!!

Comment: E se eu precisar usar `email` **ou** `cpf` junto com a senha?

Comment: @ErlonCharles é a mesma lógica só agrupar o `where` e passar os dois parâmetros, porque ele só precisa da instância para logar. Ou seja [https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping)