# Autenticação Login Laravel - Se campo na DB não for 0

Tags: php, laravel, login, auth

Na tabela de usuário eu tenho um campo chamado 'status', nele contém o nível hierárquico de cada usuário, caso esse campo seja '0' significa que o usuário está desativado, se for 1 ou superior significa que o usuário está ativo e de acordo com a numeração ele é um admin, moderador ou outra função.

A dúvida é: como faço pra que, quando o usuário realize o login, faça a verificação pra saber se o campo 'status' é > 0 (ou <> 0)?

Comment: leia esse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162965/laravel-authatempt-sempre-retorna-false/162970#162970 ele explica quando os campos não estão no padrão `Laravel` mas, o seu caso é só verificar se o campo é maior que 0.

Comment: Outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148446/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-costumizada-com-cpf-e-email/151477#151477

Comment: + um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187488/personalizando-uma-model-de-usuarios-laravel-5-4-problema-no-login/187535#187535